# Highcharts with user input

Tags: javascript, python, flask, highcharts

Below code graphs a stock price, from which the stock is hardcoded. The data is read from /data and graphed on /graph. The goal is to modify the code so a user can select their stock and have the data graphed based on their choice. I have tried this through a POST request but all attempts at this have resulted in a blank graph. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

flask

```
@app.route('/graph', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def graph():
        return render_template('graph.html')



@app.route('/data', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def data():
    current_time = time() + 3600
    stock_choice = si.get_live_price('AAPL')
    data = [current_time * 1000, stock_choice]
    response = make_response(json.dumps(data))
    response.content_type = 'application/json'
    return response
```

graph.html

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search stock e.g AAPL" name="stock_search">
    <span class="input-group-append">
        <button id="Btn" type="submit"></button>
    </span>
</form>

<div class="container-fluid" id="data-container"></div>

<script>
    var chart;

    function requestData() {
        // Ajax call to get the Data from Flask
        var requests = $.get('/data');


        var tm = requests.done(function (result) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20;

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(result, true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 2000);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'data-container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                events: {
                    load: requestData
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live Stock Price'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150,
                maxZoom: 20 * 1000,
                title: {
                    text: 'Time',
                    margin: 20
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                minPadding: 0.2,
                maxPadding: 0.2,
                title: {
                    text: 'Price',
                    margin: 20
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Current Price',
                data: []
            }]
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @RL1, You can match a user choice with data for example by using some query parameter or just use a separate request for each source. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fqcas7d1/ you can find a simple example of frontend implementation.